# possible with a homescreen webapp to close the browser

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, manifest

Is it possible to have a (webapp) icon on the homescreen, that only visit the url. Without displaying / opening the browser?

When I have a url like:

`https://feedmydog.com/?dog=lobbus&secret=top`

I want to make it a webapp, and on a click moving to the URL. So the dog gets his food. Without the user to close the browser again..

Wonder if there is another simple solution (without writing apps by myself)

Looking in the manifest, maybe there are options

"display" - not an option to hide / close
"related_applications" - maybe somehow?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I could just use:

```
setTimeout(()=> {
   window.close()
} , 5000);
```

The app will close. I'm not sure for Iphone yet. But tested on Android 7